# How to search for a sub-string in the files which contain another sub-string

Tags: grep, xargs

I wanted to search for a string in a list of files which has another string. Basically, I had to get the list of files with the first string and then do a search on these files for another string.

The following command helped:

```
grep -ril './' -e "first_string" | xargs grep -i "second_string"
```

First half of the command gives the list of files containing *first_string*.

`r` - Goes recursively into directories

`i` - String to be searched is case-insensitive

`l` - List the files with matches

Second half will take these file paths and run the second `grep` to search if the files has *second_string*.

Here, we need `xargs` to take these files and execute the second `grep` command.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/599955/edit) your question to include examples of what you already tried. Otherwise, contributors might point you in a direction that you already know doesn't work ...

Comment: Congratulations on figuring out the problem yourself. Please note, however, that your first approach to documenting that was actually correct. Don't include the answer (even if you found it yourself) in the question; rather, [answer you own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). So, you are encouraged to undelete your answer and revert the edit to your question :)

Answer (score 3):

You'd rather want:

```
grep -rilZ 'first_string' . | xargs -r0 grep -Hi 'second_string'
```

assuming GNU utilities (which you seem to be having as you're already using the `-r` GNU extension).

That is:

- use `-Z` and `xargs -0` to reliably pass the list of paths (which on Unix-like systems can contain any byte value except 0, while `xargs` without `-0` expects a very specific format).
- use `-r` for `xargs` to avoid running the second `grep` if the first one doesn't find any file (ommiting it here is no big deal, it would just cause the second `grep` to grep its empty stdin).
- options should be placed before non-option arguments.
- we use the `-H` option for the second `grep` to make sure the file name is always printed (even if only one file path ends up being passed to it) so we know where the matches are. For `grep` implementations that don't support `-H`, an alternative is to add `/dev/null` to the list of files for `grep` to look in. Then, `grep` being passed more than one filename will always print the filename.

Answer (score 0):

`find . | perl -ne 'open($fh, $_); $s1=0; $s2=0; while($line = <$fh>) { $s1=1 if($line=~/string 1/); $s2=1 if($line=~/string 2/); } ; print $_ if($s1==1 and $s2 ==1); close $fh;' | sort | uniq`

(It's a bit long to see, but this goes all on 1 line)

**Edit:** Some explanation:

- `find . |`  sends a list of all files in the directory you want to search through (`.`) to the next command (`perl`)
- `perl -ne 'COMMANDS'` loops through all the lines it receives on STDIN (so all files) and runs `COMMANDS` on each of them. The name of each file will each time end up in `$_`
- `open($fh, $_); COMMANDS; close $fh;` opens a file, binds it to the filehandle `$fh`, runs `COMMANDS` and closes it again.
- `$s1=0; $s2=0;` these vars are set to 0 again every time the next file starts (if we find a string in the current file it's set to 1)
- `while($line = <$fh>) { COMMANDS } ;` runs `COMMANDS` on every line in the file.
- `$s1=1 if($line=~/string 1/); $s2=1 if($line=~/string 2/);` if `string 1` is found in the current file `$s1` will become 1, same for `$s2`
- `print $_ if($s1==1 and $s2 ==1);` prints the filename if the strings are found.
- `| sort | uniq` sorts the filenames and filters out doubles (this should actually not be necessary)